# Adding a PivotItem-derived class to a Pivot throws an exception

Tags: windows-runtime, pivot, win-universal-app

UWP, C#. I have a `Pivot` control. I'm trying to add a `PivotItem`-derived object to the Items collection. It throws a `COMException`:

> No installed components were detected.
>
> Cannot apply a Style with TargetType 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.PivotItem' to an object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl'.

The HRESULT is 0x800f1000, if that matters.

Reproduces on a clean example. This works:

```
MyPivot.Items.Insert(1, new PivotItem() { Header = "Boo" });
```

And this exceptions:

```
MyPivot.Items.Insert(1, new BooItem() { Header = "Boo" });
```

Where `BooItem` is defined as

```
public class BooItem : PivotItem
{
    public BooItem(){}
}
```

If specified via XAML, the `PivotItem`-derived classes work in a `Pivot`. My other items in the app are all like that.

The whole codebase is a port from Windows Phone Silverlight (targeting WP8.0), it worked over there. Now, UWP is not quite the same, but still, you'd expect...

EDIT: you can add the item as invisible. The header will still appear, but the contents will be, well, invisible. Trying to make it visible causes the same exception.

There's an interesting line in the `Pivot` docs:

> Any item you add to the Pivot that is not explicitly a PivotItem is implicitly wrapped in a PivotItem.

Do objects that derive `PivotItem` count?

---

EDIT2: reproduced on a blank project. The main page XAML goes:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Pivot x:Name="ThePivot">
        <PivotItem Header="Foo">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Go" Click="OnGo"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </PivotItem>
        
    </Pivot>
</Page>
```

The code behind goes:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
namespace UWTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnGo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThePivot.Items.Insert(1, new BooItem() { Header = "Boo" });
        }
    }
    public class BooItem : PivotItem
    {
        public BooItem() { }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 update 3, target version 14393, min version the same.

EDIT: reproduced on another machine. Visual Studio 2015, brand new Unversal Windows C# project. Windows 10 Pro, v 1803 (build 17134.648).

Comment: I created `BooItem` with your code then add it to`MyPivot.Items`, it works well, I can't reproduce your issue, could share more detail about the uwp project target version or mini sample for us?

Comment: See the edit. It could be specific to VS version and/or SDK version.

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 2015 in my side, I tested with Visual Studio 2017 target version 14393. Project works well, And there is no exception throwing.

Comment: I've just created a fresh project in VS2017 v.15.8.9 targeting Windows 14393, pasted the XAML/C# above into it (modulo the namespace), ran, clicked - **same exception**. Win10 Enterprise build 17134.590.

Comment: Could you share us a mini sample that could reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I did. Create a brand new C# Universal Windows app project. Replace MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs with the code above. Fix the namespace to match the project name. Build, run, click. The only variable that we might have different that I can think of is the Windows version. Let me find another Win10 box and try there.